# how to parse json which is in form of url in html5

Tags: json, html

I am working on html5 and i have to parse json for that i have a json in the form of url.

so, please recommend me a desired way to parse json.

thanks.

Comment: You can't parse json with HTML5, you might want to use jQuery

Comment: so please can u recommend me some code related to this

Comment: You don't need to parse json, it is already javascript object, so you can use it as it is. If you like to have releated code, please describe more precise what you are trying to do.

Comment: hi, i am trying to get the data from the url in html5 code. so please can we recommend me some code related to this.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to go through and show you how to implement it, but a simple google search will help you more.

Check out the .getJSON API

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: hi, this code is not working in my case. I have a particular url which contains all the data and i want to use that in my code. so please can you help me for that. thanks.

Comment: show a sample(code) of what you have and how you want to convert it in to.